# Is there a way to optimize this query for a OR where clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following query takes 347 ms, which is too much for my application. Is there a way to optimize this query?

```
profile
MATCH (s:product {id:'4554969'})-[r]->(o)
WHERE o:ExAttrs OR o:ProdAttrs
return s.item_sku_id, TYPE(r), o;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This time is not the query time, it's the time when all the data are available (ie. when the driver have received all the data).

You can see the query time in the *table* tab.

Example :

```
Started streaming 10 records after 1 ms and completed after 2 ms
```

Your query is not parameterized, so each time you change the id in your query,  Neo4j has to compute the query plan, and so you are loosing some ms.

```
MATCH (s:product {id:$id})-[r]->(o)
WHERE o:ExAttrs OR o:ProdAttrs
return s.item_sku_id, TYPE(r), o
```

And see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/) how to use parameter  with the driver of your choice.

EDIT:

```
public String query_partial_match(String skuid, String attrKey) {

        return "MATCH (s:product {id:'" + skuid + "'})-[r]->(o) " +
                "WHERE " +
                "(o:ExAttrs OR o:ProdAttrs) AND " +
                "any(key in keys(o) WHERE key =~'(?i).*(" + attrKey + ").*') " +
                "return s.item_sku_id, s.item_name, r, o";
    }
```

I have about 50 such Java functions to dynamically generate cypher query strings, and then send the query to the 'execute' of the driver api to get the result. In the above example, I am already using the 'parameter' way to generate the proper cypher query. However, this parameterization only takes place in my query generation code, but there is no parameterization in the 'execute'. My colleague wrapped the Neo4j native driver api into a 'Neo4jSearchAPI', which has an 'execute' method to take a cypher query string as parameter to query on the graph. And my code like above is to generate such cypher query strings.

So if I want to really use parameterization,  our wrapped Neo4jSearchAPI should support this. Basically, my 50 query generation functions should be coded in the Neo4jSearchAPI, not in my own code, which only produces cypher string. Is that right?

Comment: how to parameterize the query above, for example, if it can speed up things?

Comment: please see my addition and question. Also, how faster to use query parameterization?